# Input protection close to maximum voltage

Tags: surge-protection, over-voltage-protection

I'm planning a CAN network based on the [CANbed RP2040](https://docs.longan-labs.cc/1030018/) where the boards will be connected via fairly long cables (1 to 5 metres) to a LiFePo4 battery as shown below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7snKy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The battery has a peak, end-of-charge voltage of about 29.2V, which I have currently adjusted down to 28.4V in the charger settings. Normal float voltage is about 27 V. All circuits must remain operational during charging.

The [DIO54302](https://www.semiee.com/file/DIOO/DIOO-DIO54302.pdf) regulator specifies an absolute max rating of 32V and recommended operating conditions up to 28V. The input diode D1 (ORing diode with aux power input from USB, not shown) is a [SS32](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88751/ss32.pdf) with typical Vf of 0.1 V to 0.5 V.

Questions:

1. is there a risk of inductive spikes exceeding the maximum voltage rating when SW1 is closed? (looking at you, ceramic input capacitor)
2. what sort of input filtering can I add (at the location marked '?') to protect the device and avoid having to lower the battery charge voltage any further?
3. I can select the power cable to have a cross-section between 0.75 mm2 and 2.5 mm2, does this choice affect the potential for inductive spikes?

[EDIT] After reading Tim Willams and Spehro Pefhany, I ran some simulations on LTspice. The power-on spike reached more than 60 V.

[image: schematic, initial]
[image: simulation, initial]

Adding a 470uF electrolytic eliminated the spike, but given Spehro's comments on the diode breakdown voltage I will also reduce the input voltage to 12 V for this section. The electrolytic is still needed to prevent a ~30 V spike in that case.

[image: schematic, final]
[image: simulation, final]

Comment: That's really not a lot of margin and it would be expensive and complex (maybe not practical) to try to protect the IC with such a narrow margin. What will you do if you start to get significant field failures due to things like lightning strikes nearby? What is the purpose of D1? The rating of 20V seems inadequate for reverse-voltage protection in this instance.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany D1 is actually an ORing diode with the aux power input from the USB port.

Comment: So the 20V diode could be blocking 23.4V nominally even with the USB 'on'?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany indeed, you're right. This looks like a design bug; my guess is they updated the regulator (as per the version notes) and consequently increased the voltage rating from 12 to 28 V, but forgot to update the diodes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0. It's just the wrong part for the job -- don't use it.  Pick something with 36V at the absolute minimum, preferably 40V or higher rating.  This gives enough range that transient clamping is feasible, for instance; as-is, you have simply zero headroom.

If the load is small, you might consider an LDO in front of the switching regulator -- including crude solutions such as a zener shunt regulator into a depletion-mode NMOS source follower.  This is most practical for transient limiting, such as automotive load dump, and doesn't seem important or worthwhile here.

Also, mind your current consumption.  If all you need is 1A -- if even that -- choose a smaller regulator.  The 3A rating of this device means 3A of partial-fault current is available, making liabilities downstream.

Regarding [context added in comments, at time of writing], you might consider wired-OR-ing 3.3V from an LDO from USB5V, instead of 28V.  Then you don't need a switching regulator with low dropout.  Note that USB sources aren't generally capable of 1A (or without negotiation).

1. See [Why did my DC/DC Buck Circuit fail?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/704381/why-did-my-dc-dc-buck-circuit-fail) for the most recent run-down on this topic.
2. An electrolytic capacitor, probably; a TVS might also be welcome.

Filtering for EMC purposes is undefined, as you've given no information to go on.  We would need to know at least: where the battery is placed relative to everything else, if the cables are exposed, or hugging or inside metal members, if anything else connects to the battery, power supply, etc., what test levels are, etc. etc.  Preferably, complete schematics and assembly diagrams for the system would be provided, as well as a guide to where and what connector(s) are mated and to what.

3. No, only the cross-sectional geometry; the transmission line impedance.  Typical twin-lead is in the ballpark of 100Ω, giving ca. 0.5 µH/m inductance per length.

Comment: Thanks for the answer; that's really helpful. My concern is mostly about how to prevent the inductive spike on power-on; EMC isn't a concern at this stage. It seems there's simply not enough headroom for a TVS here, so I'll try to simulate the effect of an electrolytic capacitor in LTspice using your figure for the cable inductance. USB is not going to be connected in use (only when programming).

Comment: Re: the choice of parts; the power regulator is not my design, it's built into the CAN board. My options are limited to adding something on the input or changing the system voltage.

Comment: Ah, got it. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I added some simulation results.